# Subtracting 2 datetime64 columns in pandas using @numpy.vectorize

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

I have a pandas DataFrame with 2 date columns: Created and Resolved.

`Created               Resolved
0  2019-09-24 20:48:25 2019-10-31 22:07:36
1  2019-09-27 00:54:39 2019-11-18 17:24:13
2  2019-09-27 20:07:50                 NaT
3  2019-09-27 20:17:10 2019-10-22 17:34:08
4  2019-09-27 22:01:29 2019-10-22 17:34:08
5  2019-09-30 17:41:02                 NaT
6  2019-10-02 04:36:32                 NaT
7  2019-10-03 17:42:15 2019-10-22 17:34:09
8  2019-10-03 18:34:29                 NaT
10 2019-10-08 18:40:45 2019-10-22 17:34:09`

Here is the info.

`class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 10
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Created     10 non-null datetime64[ns]
Resolved    6 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2)`

I want to check how many days it took to resolve:

`@numpy.vectorize
def age(res, cr):
    if pd.isnull(res):
        return pd.to_datetime('today')-cr
    return res-cr`

When I pass the columns to the function `df.diff=age(df.Resolved,df.Created)` it brings an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need replace missing values in `Resolved` column by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and then subtract column `Created`, solution is already vectorized:

```
df['diff'] = df.Resolved.fillna(pd.to_datetime('today')) - df.Created
print (df)
               Created            Resolved                     diff
0  2019-09-24 20:48:25 2019-10-31 22:07:36         37 days 01:19:11
1  2019-09-27 00:54:39 2019-11-18 17:24:13         52 days 16:29:34
2  2019-09-27 20:07:50                 NaT 159 days 13:42:59.435281
3  2019-09-27 20:17:10 2019-10-22 17:34:08         24 days 21:16:58
4  2019-09-27 22:01:29 2019-10-22 17:34:08         24 days 19:32:39
5  2019-09-30 17:41:02                 NaT 156 days 16:09:47.435281
6  2019-10-02 04:36:32                 NaT 155 days 05:14:17.435281
7  2019-10-03 17:42:15 2019-10-22 17:34:09         18 days 23:51:54
8  2019-10-03 18:34:29                 NaT 153 days 15:16:20.435281
10 2019-10-08 18:40:45 2019-10-22 17:34:09         13 days 22:53:24
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It resolves my problem. However, I would like to understand why the function doesn't work

Comment: @Ani - I think problem is with call function, need `age(df.Resolved,df.Created)`

Comment: I accepted the answer . I edited my question, too. The correct function call still doesn't work.